Interpretation of a stochastic Schrodinger equation
Suppose we have a linear stochastic Schrodinger equation (SDE) describing the evolution of a system in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space:
$$ d\psi(t) = \left(-iH(t) - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^dR_j^{\dagger}R_j \right)\psi(t)dt + \sum_{j=1}^d R_j\psi(t)dW_j(t).$$
In the literature, the processes $W_j(t)$ are interpreted as results of weak continuous measurements, and $\psi(t)$ describes the state of a system at time $t$ conditioned on measurement outcomes $W_j(t)$ from time $[0,t]$.
The interpretation above gets me confused. Does it mean that the SDE above only applies to systems that undergo measurements by a human observer and not, say, an environment? If the observer was an environment, how can we know $W_j(t)$ and hence, how can we condition the state $\psi(t)$?
I'm particularly interested in whether the SDE above could be used in a setting where an environment continuously learns (hence perturbs) the principal system. If the SDE can be applied in this setting, can we still assume that we know $W_j(t)$, or is it possible to obtain the actual realization $W_j(t)$ given that it is an environment that is doing the measurements?
